# Getting error after running simple xml code in Rstudio

Tags: r, xml

When I run this code, I get error. Not sure why this is happening. I am using Rstudio 64bit

```
library(XML)
fileURL <- "https://www.w3schools.com//xml//simple.xml"
docs <- xmlTreeParse(fileURL,useInternal=TRUE)
rootNode <- xmlRoot(docs)
xmlName(rootNode)
```

Error Seen as below

> xmlName(rootNode)
>   Error in xmlName(rootNode) : object 'rootNode' not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply call `readLines` to retrieve content of URL page. Usually you can load a URL with `isURL=TRUE` argument but `xmlTreeParse` does not support `https` but `http` or `ftp` per [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/XML/versions/3.98-1.19/topics/xmlTreeParse):

> **isURL** indicates whether the file argument refers to a URL (accessible via ftp or http)

```
content <- readLines(fileURL)

docs <- xmlTreeParse(content, useInternal=TRUE)

rootNode <- xmlRoot(docs)
xmlName(rootNode)
# [1] "breakfast_menu"
```